Can you avoid restart propagation on failure to PartOf target with systemd 239
I'm not even sure this is possible with the version that we have available.
I have 5 databases that I want to be able to restart at once or individually. I have set up a target for this. I added PartOf to each of the database services to enforce the stop requests.
Should one of the database services fail, it is set to restart, but this propagates to the target file which then performs a restart on all the running databases.
[Unit]
Description=The database target db.target

[Unit]
Description=The %i database service
PartOf=db.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/not -i relevant

I know that in version 249 they added a PropagateStopTo, but I'm not sure I can get this on a RHEL8 system without doing some sketchy things. If I had that available, I wouldn't need the PartOf. Although I do want the systemctl restart db.target to restart all the databases.
Am I just packing too much into one target file? I'm not certain I want to create a web of targets that are going to be overly complex in order to handle this.
As of now, they are not using systemd to handle the databases, so I could definitely pack the start/stop/restart into a shell script that takes parameters.
However, that is the mess they are currently fighting with.

Should one of the database services fail, it is set to restart, but this propagates to the target file which then performs a restart on all the running databases. But that's not an expected behavior for having PartOf=db.target in the services. From systemd.unit regarding PartOf=: Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
